# Haskell module ,parse error on input 'sayhello'"`

Tags: haskell

```
module sayhello  
( inChinese  
, inSpanish   
) where 
inChinese  = "Ni Hao"  
inSpanish=  "Hola"

import sayhello

main = do

    print sayhello.inChinese
    print sayhello.inSpanish
```

I got error from this code.  `"module.hs:1:8: parse error on input 'sayhello'"`
I dont understand why, need your help, thanks.

Edited:
1 found on problem that I should use upper case as module name.

1. I got another problem:
   it shows:

   Output was redirected with -o, but no output will be generated
   because there is no Main module.

Why is that? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to have all your import statements after `module ModName (export list) where` and your actual code.  Also, you don't import the module you're currently in:

```hs
module sayhello  
    ( inChinese  
    , inSpanish   
    ) where 

inChinese = "Ni Hao"  
inSpanish = "Hola"

main = do
    print inChinese
    print inSpanish
```

Comment: and module names have to be uppercase, just like types

Comment: @jberryman right, thanks. But I got another problem. see original post please

Comment: @NoName I think you can figure this out with a little thought and research.